# Twig function return a template

Tags: php, twig, symfony

Is it possible for a twig function to return a twig template?

For example

```
class ToTimeExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            'totime' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'toTime')
        );
    }

    public function toTime ($string) {
        $time = strtotime($string);
        return {"time.html.twig", $time};
        //return a twig template and pass $time variable
    }

}
```

time.html.twig

```
<h1>{{time}}</h1>
```

Usage

```
{{ totime('now') }}
```

Comment: Do you really need a function, why not just `{% include 'time.html.twig' %}`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov This was just an example. There is a more complex logic running in the backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `Twig` environment if you set the proper options. Then you can render another template inside the method.

```
class ToTimeExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    public function getFunctions() {
         return array(
            'totime' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'toTime', ['needs_environment' => true,])
         );
    }

    public function toTime (Twig_Environment $twig, $string) {
        return $twig->render('time.html.twig', [ 'time' => strtotime($string),]);
    }
}
```